# Joomla Array - Database

Tags: php, arrays, joomla

How to set up an array so that instead of maximum - an array on multiples of 30 is shown

i.e $max = 30, 60, 90, 120, 150......and so on

If array $max matches on multiple of 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210..... then it should display message that limits are exhausted.

```
// Define the maximum Submissions
$max = 30;

// Get the current logged in user.
$user = JFactory::getUser();

// Get a database connection.
$db   = JFactory::getDbo();
$query   = $db->getQuery(true);

// Setup the query.
$query->select('COUNT('.$db->qn('Username').')')
    ->from($db->qn('#__rsform_submissions'))
    ->where($db->qn('Username').'='.$db->q($user->get('username')));

$db->setQuery($query);
$counter = $db->loadResult();

if ($counter = $max){
  $formLayout = '<p style="color:blue;">Your Limits are Exhausted </p>';
}
```

Comment: Please try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hello, Would do it from next Q, onwards. Is it possible to get answer of present question asked in this page itself.

Comment: The reason I ask is because it may get more attention on Joomla Stack Exchange. It's exactly the same as Stackoverflow but a dedicated area for Joomla related questions ;)

Comment: The last if is incorrect: it's setting `$counter = $max` instead of comparing.

Comment: Also could you clarify what you want to do? I did not understand.

Comment: So if people have 31 submissions they have not reached the max? Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: Hello - Actually i intend to put in a restriction every time - when a user reaches 30 submission or its multiples for instance 30, 60, 90 so that the user can email us report and when the report is mailed - we will mark an exception for the user for a day like - // Function for User Limits
$arr = array(1201); // DEFINE THE USER ID'S HERE 
if (in_array($user->get('id'), $arr)){ - so that he can submit the form again